# form response values always give off undefined, trying to push to backend eventually, tried it 2 ways

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Okay so I've attempted this 2 different ways and both give me a value of "undefined" instead of the answer that the user puts into the form, I'm using material UI forms if that helps.

The 2 ways I did is:
1. I have a button at the end that submits, which is the preferred way I want to do it and then display the data after. 
2. I'm trying it as the user types so using onChange and it'll update on the UI as the user types.

Neither ways have been working because even when I submit or type I get console.log saying "undefined" each time, so I don't even know if I'm pulling results.

My end goal is to get the form data into variables and then upload those into the backend (to use on other pages of the app) and from the backend pull the information to display on this page so the user can see their information.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

```
class AccountPage extends React.Component {

  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      socMed1: ''
    }
  }

  handleSubmit(event){
    alert("test")



  }

  handleChange (event) {
    this.setState( {[event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    console.log(event.name)
  }


  render() {
    return (



      <div>

      <h1>
        {this.email}
      </h1>



        <form action="/" method="POST" onSubmit={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); this.handleSubmit(); } }>        

        <TextField
          id="standard-name"
          style={{ margin: 15 }}
          label="Name"
          margin="normal"

          name="email"   
          value={this.state.email} 
          onChange={event => this.handleChange(event)}
        />

        <TextField
          id="standard-name"
          style={{ margin: 15 }}
          label="Location"
          margin="normal"
        />

        <TextField
          id="standard-select-socialmedia"
          select
          style={{ margin: 15 }}
          label="Select"
          SelectProps={{
            MenuProps: {},
          }}
          helperText="Please select your main social media"
          margin="normal"

          name = "socMed1"
          value={this.state.socMed1} 
          onChange={event => this.handleChange(event)}

        >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have submit button at the bottom, 
something like (you can use material ui one) 
`<button onSubmit={(event) => this.handleSubmit(event)} />`
and try adding this to your `alert`
`` alert(`email: ${this.state.email}, socMed1: ${this.state.socMed1}`) ``
then you will see what user typed in field 
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

a functional component with form. checkout Just do some research this is just HTML functionality. if you want to use class component you can go ahead but just use "**this.handleSubmit** in onSubmit form would work

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const Demo = () => {
  const handleSubmit = event => {
    const formData = new FormData(event.target);
    //does not resets the form
    event.preventDefault();
    // accessing each values
    for (var [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
      console.log(key, value);
    }
    // posting you values to api
    fetch("/api/form-submit-url", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData
    });
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
      // names are important because this will be treated as a key value pair in handle submit.
          <TextField id="standard-basic" name="user" label="user" />
          <TextField id="standard-basic" name="email" label="email" />
          <TextField id="standard-basic" name="password" label="password" />
          <Button type="submit" variant="contained">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```